# Who finally had Pushpak Viman in the end?

Tags: ramayana, vibhishana, ayodhya

After returning to Ayodhya after killing Ravan on Pushpak Viman, whom did Lord Ram gave it to ?

Comment: No...it does come back...then Sri Rama carries out a worship ritual using paddy...and..it goes back to Kubera.But, yes, Sri Rama...can call back the mystical aerial car at will, whenever/if Sri Rama wanted..

Answer (score -2):

I think it must be Vibhishana. 
It is a simple logic. The chariot belonged to the king of Lanka and after Vibhishana became the king of Lanka, it became his property.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers on this site should be elaborate enough to solve the questioner's doubts and should contain relevant texts from Hindu scriptures, eg, Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads, etc to support your answer. Please either edit your answer to provide more details or delete/comment instead.

Comment: Logic would be personal opinion which is alone not endorsed here. You [need to cite some sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277).